# Why environment variable is not working in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /xxx.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=MAKE_CACHE:true]

<If "%{ENV:MAKE_CACHE} =~ /^true$/">
    Header set CUSTOM_HEADER "custom value or my header"
</If>
```

I simplified the htaccess but you can get the idea: I set an environment variable if the user tries to reuqest "xxx.php" and latter I set a header CUSTOM_HEADER but for some reason Apache is not "seeing" the variable "MAKE_CACHE" when gets the to the line "". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using apache 2.4* ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the non-intuitive sequence of Apache internal processing.

The expression for `<If ...` is evaluated much earlier than *any* `RewriteRule`, much less `RewriteRule` inside of `.htaccess`, which happens even later.

There are two options to get the ordering right:

- Use `SetEnvIf` (not inside `<Location>`) to set the initial var, instead of `<If ...`. It runs really early when it's specified that way.
- Use an expression-based condition clause on the `Header` directive. This delays the execution.

Good luck!

edit: tested example:

```
Header always set FOO BAR "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/xxx.php$#"
```

Comment: You got it! You are indeed right, I read that before on google but could not confirm. Thanks a lot! Your 2 options are great but I am not too smart on htaccess to accomplish that. Could you provide a clue of how I can do this using the first option? The second option I think I can do: you are saying I should set a HEADER when the rewritecond is true, and later check if the HEADER is present? How can I check if the header is present and how can I set a header with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Nice! Could you explain why did you use "m#"?

Comment: Also, could you please tell me how do I check if the FOO BAR is seted so I can set my CUSTOM_HEADER ?